# How can I keep a form with divs from breaking line?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been struggling because I have this form that has different inputs on sub divs. Whenever I put the opening form tag before the first input, the line breaks. If I put it after it, it will stay fine. I have tried adding:

```
display:inline
```

to different classes, but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tL50dhcu/

Can anyone help me keep it in line?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Here is a more succinct way to do what you are trying to do: http://codepen.io/dcain19/pen/xVVyao

Try the example below. Notice how the search input was put inside the `input-group-btn` class. Now, you will have to change your `border-radius` on the button to make the right borders rounded, but that should get you what you need.

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="{% url 'search' %}">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search" name="search" required />

              <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="filter">Industry</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="searchIndustry" name="industry">
                      <option value="any">Any</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="filter">Country</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="searchCountry" name="country">
                      <option value="any">Any</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.form-horizontal {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

if you make the container of the form flex , and set it to nowrap